# Grep/Sed replace small text in large .sql file

Tags: mysql, bash, replace, sed, command-line

I have a large .sql file of size ~ 220 MB.

Now in that I have a TRIGGER statement in that file, which uses a different user than the mysql database user, i am trying to import database with, so it gives below error when trying to import database:

```
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 9732: TRIGGER command denied to user 'user_name'@'localhost' for table 'sales_flat_creditmemo'
```

Now how can I find all lines containing the TRIGGER statements and change "user_name" to mysql user "username_actual" in the whole file without even opening it. Opening this file in Geany also causes the Geany to crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `grep` and `sed` for in-place replacement, without actually opening the file.

```
grep -Iril 'TRIGGER' sql_file | xargs sed -i 's/user_name/username_actual/g'
```

The purposes of the flags are:-

`-I` -> to ignore binary files while  doing `grep` on files. ( may not be applicable here)
`-r` -> recursive search under all sub-levels of directories
`-i` -> Ignore case (case insensitive search)
`-l` -> Just print the file-name in which the match is found.

Check more in the [`man grep`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/grep1.html) page.

There is also one cool alternate way of using `Vim` in `Ex` mode for performing the substitution in-place.

```
ex -sc '/TRIGGER/s/user_name/username_actual/|x' file
```

Also one last solution using `sed` alone for in-place replacement

```
sed -i '/TRIGGER/s/user_name/username_actual/g'
```

Comment: Can you explain the grep params in your answer, what is `I` is for in there ?

Comment: And if the OP knows what file contains the TRIGGER statements already, why bother with the `grep` at all?

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers and comments. Please upvote this question if you find it worthy.